# How to modify this kind of file by Ruby

Tags: ruby, algorithm

I have a file like:

```
Fruit.Store={
    #order:123, order:345, order:456
    #order:789
    "customer-id:12345,item:store/apple" = 10;    
    "customer-id:23456,item:store/banana" = 10;   
    "customer-id:23456,item:store/watermelon" = 10;
    #order:987
    "customer-id:67890,item:store/pear" = 10;
}
```

Except the comments, each line has the same format: customer-id and item:store/ are fixed, and customer-id is a 5-digit number. There are about 1000 unique lines in the file.

When a new order is placed based on same customer-id and fruit type with different quantity, I want the order id be added in the comment line above and update the quantity, like if a new order 001 is placed with information "customer-id:23456,item:store/watermelon" = 5;  than we should have a new file:

```
Fruit.Store={
    #order:123, order:345, order:456
    #order:789, order:000
    "customer-id:12345,item:store/apple" = 10;    
    "customer-id:23456,item:store/banana" = 10;   
    "customer-id:23456,item:store/watermelon" = 5;
    #order:987
    "customer-id:67890,item:store/pear" = 10;
}
```

Is it possible to do so in an efficient way? Because file has to be read and written line by line, how could we detect the matched information and go back to previous line to do modification? Thank you.

Comment: Where did the file come from? What program generated it?

Comment: Don't keep the data in this format. Keep it in the database or in another file in a format that is easy to parse (JSON, CSV, XML etc). Generate this file in the desired format after each update of the data but never read from it.

Comment: It is a file which was generated manually, for some reasons, it has to be in txt format... thanks

Comment: How often is there an update?

Comment: And I assume the new order id added should be '001', not '000'. And how is the location of the comment determined?

Answer (score 0):

In short: no, it is not possible to do so *in an efficient way.* Your best bet is to open separate files for reading and writing, but even then you'll effectively be rewriting the entire file over and over.

Ultimately, you should be using some sort of referential database, like SQL. Those databases were practically invented for this exact use-case.

I really don't like to tell people that the only solution is to do something entirely different from what they're doing, but in this case I can't stress enough how poorly text files scale for managing data.